# Can I cause JsDoc3 to omit the <footer> tag with the date in it?

Tags: jsdoc, jsdoc3

JSDoc outputs a date in the footer of each page:

```
<footer>
    Documentation generated by <a href="https://github.com/jsdoc3/jsdoc">JSDoc 3.2.0</a> on Fri Jan 17 2014 14:30:54 GMT-0800 (PST)
</footer>
```

So whenever I rebuild my library, all the documentation files look like they've changed to Git.  That's not desirable -- I only want to commit these docs when they actually change in content.

Can I cause JsDoc to *not* output this footer at all?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have some modest experience with creating jsdoc 3 templates and I've looked at the code to check what you are asking. Here is what I found:

- `<footer>` is hardcoded in the default template's `layout.tmpl` file. By hardcoded, I mean the element itself is not optional.
- I've not seen any code in the default template's `publish.js` file that would somehow remove `<footer>` when processing `layout.tmpl`.

So to remove this footer you'd have to use a customized template or do some sort of post-processing on the files generated by jsdoc 3.

With versions prior to 3.3.0, removing `<footer>` from the template would mean copying the whole default template and making the change to `layout.tmpl`. Version 3.3.0, which is currently in alpha, [will provide the possibility](https://github.com/jsdoc3/jsdoc/issues/480) to basically tell jsdoc 3 to use the default template but with a different `layout.tmpl` file, which will make customizing templates much easier.

Answer (score 4):

I submitted a PR for this issue (https://github.com/jsdoc3/jsdoc/pull/916), and it's now on the 3.3.0 branch.

This change was not published to NPM at the time I'm writing this answer, but you can require the 3.3.0 branch from git:

```
"jsdoc": "git+https://git@github.com/jsdoc3/jsdoc.git#releases/3.3"
```

Afterwards, you can add the following field to your config file:

```
{
    ...
    "templates": {
        ...
        "default": {
            "includeDate": false
        }
    },
    ...
}
```

Notice this option is only available for the default jsdoc template.